# Is it possible to match multiple paths with preferred prefix?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have two locations '/mysite/india' and '/mysite/usa' that share same definition. I know I can specify this using regex (without **^**). which I do not want to use as this is a very frequently hit endpoint. Anotehr way to is to duplicate the whole block with two exact matches(/mysite/usa and /mysite/india). I am wondering if there is a way to use 'preferred prefix' instead? I tried following with https://nginx.viraptor.info/ and it doesn't work. Is this syntax wrong or is this just not supported?

```
server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
 access_log   logs/mydomain.access.log  main;
 
location ^~ /mysite(/usa|/india)$
{
  root    /var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs;
  expires 30d;
 }

 location / {
  proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `^~` modifier for the location block basically means "do not check regular expressions", so you can't use regex syntax for the match part.

The only way to match multiple paths with a single location block is to use regular expressions (with `~` or `~*`).

If you are primarily concerned about performance, then the best option would be to use the "=" modifier with separate blocks for each path. Note that this means exact match, *not* a prefix match - so `= /mysite/usa` would not match `.../mysite/usa/` or `.../mysite/usa/index.html`. If you do need prefix matching, then the most performant option would be the `^~` modifier (again, with separate blocks).

Ideally, you should test the performance impact of the different options on your servers - unless you have a large amount of regex-based location blocks, you will likely find that the performance hit is so negligible that the maintenance advantage of using the regex option is well worth it.